# What does it mean to add an iterator to a string in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am new to coding and I am struggling with some doubts. One of them is the specific meaning of some code parts.
For example, here it is a chunk of code that I really do not understand:

```
char    *ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    if (*to_find == 0)
         return (str);
    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
         j = 0;
         while (to_find[j] == str[i + j])
         {
              if (to_find[j + 1] == '\0')
              {
                  return (str + i);
              }
              j++;
         }
         i++;
    }
    return (0);
 }
```

My question is: what does it mean to return (str + i)? Isn't str a string (so, an array) and i an int? There has to be something that I do not understand. Thank you all.

Comment: `str` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: `str` is a  pointer to a `char`.  `return (str + i);` returns that pointer plus `i`.  Is there something more needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no real iterators in C, your `i` is just an integer variable. There are also no *real* strings, `str` is just a pointer to (an array of) characters, that by convention are treated as a string.

Hence, `(str + i)` adds an integer to a pointer, and that's defined as starting at the pointed-to element, then going that many elements forward. It's the same as `&str[i]`, i.e. treating `str` as an array, and taking the address of the element at index `i`.

In other words, if you have

```
char *str = "foobar";
int i = 3;
```

then `str + 3` points to the `b`, or the substring `bar`.